# prevent input for double spaces in character arrayin C++

Tags: c++, validation, input

I have to avoid double spaces, double ! and double full stops in my character array. I must have to use character array btw.
e.g  Valid data: "It is raining.!"         Invalid Data:  "It  is  raining!!."   (it is only example)

I tried the following way but am not getting desired result. Plz help me.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isValidData( char data[60] );
int main()
{
    char data[60];
    cin.getline(data,60);
    bool name = isValidData(data);
    cout<<name;
}
bool isValidData( char data[60] ) 
{
    int i=0;
    while(data[i]!='\0') {
        if ( data[i]==' ' && data[i]=='.' && data[i]=='!'){
            if ( data[i+1]==' ' && data[i+1]=='.' && data[i+1]=='!')
                return false;
            }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the input and the desired/actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because no character can simultaneously be equal to `,`, `!`, and .
Even if you fix that, you will still flag `,!` as invalid.

Test the property directly instead:

```
bool isValidData( char data[60] ) 
{
    int i=0;
    while(data[i]!='\0' && data[i+1]!='\0') {
        if ((data[i]==' ' || data[i]=='.' || data[i]=='!') && data[i+1]==data[i]) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```